# Openmp Inizialization Vectors

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, openmp

I would like to know why It's more slow if I use openmp to initialize vectors using this code:

dimension=7000;
chunksize=700;

These for are in two different places.

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule (static, chunksize) private(i)
for (i=0;i<dimension;i++){
        visited[i]=0;
        used[i]=0;
        connected[i]=0;
        }

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,chunksize) private(j) 
for(j=0;j<dimension;j++){
    if (mat[next][j]) {
             visited[j]=1;
             connected[j]=tag;
    }

}
```

I have 4 core(2 physical,2 logical), and these are speed for the first for:
Without Openmp: 0.000048
With Openmp: 0.000168

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenMP does result in some overhead. I don't know what you have 7000 of, but 7000 of a small type like a double or int may fit in the fastest L1 cache of a single processor and certainly fits in the next bigger cache, meaning that you're parallelizing a code that's already enjoying close to best-case performance in the serial case.

Also, if your `mat` variable only exists in one place, the threads could be fighting over references to it, resulting in contention and slowing things down.

Comment: Best case performance here would probably be to use `memset`.